# prestashop displayFieldName() overload for fields translation

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I created a new module using MVC.

In my ObjectModel Class, I overload displayFieldName() function in order to get human reading fields errors when users doesn't fill a form well.

For example: "The Start date field is required" instead of "The start_date field is required".

I can't found how to translate this field within this function

```
/* Overload */
public static function displayFieldName($field, $class = __CLASS__, $htmlentities = true, Context $context = null)
{
    $fieldname = array(
        'date_start' => 'Start date',
        'title' => 'Title',
    );
    if ($fieldname[$field])
        return $fieldname[$field];
    else
        return $field;
}
```

I tried many things but can't find the usual l() function from here.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do that at all. It is already implemented in PrestaShop.

BackOffice > Localization > Translation > Field name translations

Note that during the installation you must copy your object model file in classes folder.

So if you have Object Model called MyDataObject you must have:

classes/MyDataObject.php in which you must have

```
<?php

class MyDataObjectCore extends ObjectModel
{

}
```

Do not forget the "Core" suffix, because the Fields Translation functionality needs it.

Comment: Thanks, it works after copying the class as you said and clearing the cache/class_index.php file.
I see that translations edited that way goes to /translations/lang/fields.php, any way to copy existing field translation during install?

Comment: You can open /translations/lang/fields.php and add after the last assigning a new one:

$_FIELDS['Zone_b068931cc450442b63f5b3d276ea4297'] = 'name';

the array index is "ClassName" + underscore + MD5 of the field.

$key = $class.'_'.md5($field);